# How to run java+selenium method continuously?

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, java

There is a functionality like in sometimes one of modal pops up and there is a button on it. If the modal pops up user needs to click on that button. This is a continuous process and I need to automate it. How to handle this situation using selenium with java? My code is as below,

```
public void Orders() throws InterruptedException {
    OrdersPage op = new OrdersPage(driver);
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 15);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Reject')]")));
    //op.clickAccept();
    op.clickReject();
```

How to can I run this one continuously? (may be once a day or until stopped manually)?

Comment: Why do you want to run this continuously? How often does the modal pop open? I'm struggling to understand the use case.

Comment: Hi @LeeJensen, bcoz this is a web site for a restaurant and we need to accept receiving orders for now. So we cannot assume the modal popup time. modal pops up if someone place an order.

Comment: @Rush910 Are you using this in a test? Or are you using it in an actual user environment? If it's a test you should have control over the popup time.

Comment: hi @corsiKa, This is on actual env.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your code in a loop to have it run forever. Just add a sleep after each iteration so you don't hammer your CPU and network.

```
while(true) {
   ... your code
   Thread.sleep(250);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This scenario is faced mostly in medical device software testing where unwanted pop ups occur on the screen.

Below code will wait for one day(`withTimeout` wait), if the pop up is displayed early then it will click the 'reject' option from pop up(`pollingEvery` wait)

```
FluentWait wait = new FluentWait(driver);

wait.withTimeout(1, TimeUnit.DAYS);

wait.pollingEvery(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.ignoring(NoSuchElementException.class);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'Reject')]")));
```